# Can I utilize vectorization to improve performance instead of iterating over QGIS Features?

Tags: pyqgis, geopandas, performance, centroids, standalone

I am using Python to write a standalone application with QGIS. The application uses `requests` to allow the user to update a shapefile from the internet on demand. After fetching the shapefile, I need to compute the centroid of each polygon at runtime. There are over 200,000 features in the layer.

Using QGIS, I can compute the centroids like this:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsApplication

qgs = QgsApplication([], True)
qgs.initQgis()

project = QgsProject.instance()
project.read("/path/to/my/project")
layer = project.mapLayersByName("myLayerName")[0]

before = datetime.now()
centroids = [f.geometry().centroid() for f in parcels.getFeatures()]
after = datetime.now()

print(after - before, "seconds")
# 0:00:05.85 seconds
```

However, the following code using `geopandas` utilizes vectorization through `numpy` on the backend, performing the same computations and assigning the values to a `geopandas` Series:

```py
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file("/path/to/downloaded/shapefile.shp")

before = datetime.now()
gdf["centroids"] = gdf.centroid
after = datetime.now()

print(after - before, "seconds")
# 0:00:00.59 seconds
```

I'm using `qgis.core.QgsMapCanvas` for the main viewer and have already loaded the project and shapefile at this point in the application. Loading the attribute table into a `GeoDataFrame` provides even worse performance - probably due to the multiple loops required:

```py
before = datetime.now()
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(parcels.getFeatures()]
gdf["geometry"] = [f.geometry() for f in parcels.getFeatures()]
after = datetime.now()

print(after - before, "seconds")
# 0:00:12.57 seconds
```

I'm aware that going the `geopandas` route will require me to `import geopandas`, either `gpd.read_file` or convert it from the `layer`, and probably `gdf.to_file`, all of which will likely make `geopandas` a less efficient solution overall.

Is there a more efficient way to (a) load the layer into a `GeoDataFrame` (and hopefully save the resulting geodataframe to a shapefile) or (b) compute and store the parcel centroids using PyQGIS?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "vectorization" here? What is not satisfactory about your existing code and why?

Comment: The timings you show don't tell even close to the full story here. You don't include the loading time of the shapefile to GeoDataFrame with `gpd.read_file` which is a lot longer than the full PyQGIS version. if you benchmark while including loading from shapefile you get a completely reversed result. with geopandas being really slow. Benchmarking loading and centroid combined, I get 1.4s your first example, 30s full geopandas, 1.1s @Taras's processing solution on a 30000 polygon shapefile

Answer (score 1):

What if you simply try the ["Centroids"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgiscentroids) geoalgorithm?

```py
from qgis import processing

params = {
    'INPUT' : "/path/to/downloaded/shapefile.shp",
    'ALL_PARTS' : False,
    'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
    }
    
result = processing.run("native:centroids", params)
```

Additionally, you may try the following:

```py
import numpy as np
from qgis.core import QgsProject

def centroid_py(layer):
    return np.array([feat.geometry().centroid() for feat in layer.getFeatures()])
    
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("YOUR_LAYER_NAME")[0]
centroid_py(layer))
```

Also, see this [GeoPandas issue](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/430) about *optimizing vectorized operations*.

Comment: Probably because it does not use [vectorization](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_programming)

Comment: hah, again you. Let the mess begin :) However, thank you for the wiki page